# How to render Video on Software Layer in Android

Tags: android, android-view, android-canvas, hardware-acceleration, android-viewgroup

I have a use-case where I need to draw some paths on Android Canvas of a ViewGroup in a ViewGroup whose hierarchy also contains a Video.

As per https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel#scaling , there are problems with scaling of paths on older Android versions.

However, when I try to disable hardware acceleration at the View level as per https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/hardware-accel#controlling , it seems the viewgroup cannot render a video in another view in the same hierarchy.

Is there any way to work around this?